# Selenium - Python - AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get Selenium working with Chrome, but I keep running into this error message (and others like it):

> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

The same problem occurs with `find_element_by_id()`, `find_element_by_class()`, etc.

I also could not call `send_keys()`.

I am just running the test code provided at *[ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome - Getting started](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)*.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Program Files/Chrome Driver/chromedriver.exe")  # Path to where I installed the web driver

driver.get('http://www.google.com/');

time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!

search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')

search_box.submit()

time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!

driver.quit()
```

I am using Google Chrome version 103.0.5060.53 and downloaded ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.53 from *[Downloads](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)*.

When running the code, Chrome opens and navigates to google.com, but it receives the following output:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Programming Projects\Python Projects\Clock In\clock_in.py:21: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Program Files/Chrome Driver/chromedriver.exe")  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58397/devtools/browser/edee940d-61e0-4cc3-89e1-2aa08ab16432
[9556:21748:0627/083741.135:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [08:37:41.131] USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[9556:21748:0627/083741.149:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [08:37:41.148] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[9556:21748:0627/083741.156:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [08:37:41.155] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[9556:21748:0627/083741.157:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [08:37:41.156] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[9556:21748:0627/083741.157:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [08:37:41.156] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\[REDACTED]", line 27, in <module>
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'
[21324:19948:0627/083937.892:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

*Note: I replaced the file path for this post.*

I don't think that the DevTools listening section is related to the issue, but I thought I would include it, just in case.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Selenium just removed that method in version `4.3.0`. See the CHANGES: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

```
Selenium 4.3.0
* Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)
* Deprecated Opera support has been removed (#10630)
* Fully upgraded from python 2x to 3.7 syntax and features (#10647)
* Added a devtools version fallback mechanism to look for an older version when mismatch occurs (#10749)
* Better support for co-operative multi inheritance by utilising super() throughout
* Improved type hints throughout
```

You now need to use:

```py
driver.find_element("name", "q")
```

In your example, it would become:

```py
search_box = driver.find_element("name", "q")

search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')

search_box.submit()
```

For improved reliability, you should consider using `WebDriverWait` in combination with `element_to_be_clickable`.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I do wish that someone would update the ChromeDriver getting started page to include this new method, it would have saved a lot of headache.

Comment: NOTE that if you want to find several elements you have to add an ```s```, so instead of ```find_elements_by_*``` it is now ```find_elements()```. See this very well done SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium

Comment: works as well with deprecated `find_element_by_id()` which becomes `find_element("id", "some_id")` - great, thanks

Comment: why use strings when you can use symbolic string constants? ...

Answer (score 62):

You need to import [Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver) using this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Next use this API:

| Old API | New API |
| --- | --- |
| find_element_by_id(‘id’) | find_element(By.ID, ‘id’) |
| find_element_by_name(‘name’) | find_element(By.NAME, ‘name’) |
| find_element_by_xpath(‘xpath’) | find_element(By.XPATH, ‘xpath’) |

and so on.

Source: *[Fixing Selenium AttributeError: ‘WebDriver’ object has no attribute ‘find_element_by_xpath’](https://pythoninoffice.com/fixing-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find_element_by_xpath/)*

Answer (score 36):

find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are deprecated. You can use ***find_element()*** instead.

First you have to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Then you can use it with:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, " ")
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, " ")

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, " ")
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, " ")
```

etc.. see find_element() API for all usage

Answer (score 9):

Thank you [michael-mintz and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773206/selenium-python-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-el/72773269#72773269) [federikowsky for giving the clue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773206/selenium-python-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-el/72773349#72773349) to the root cause.

In my case, I couldn't edit the code to be compatible with the latest Selenium version. So, as a workaround, I downgraded my Selenium to 4.2.0.

For Python 3:

1. Make sure that your Selenium is 4.3.0 or higher.
   Start a Python interactive session and run:

   ```
   >>> import selenium
   >>> selenium.__version__
   ```
2. Downgrade your Selenium

- Either edit dependencies file (***requirements.txt***) and mention a specific version:

  ```
  selenium==4.2.0
  ```
- Or, if you can't change dependencies file (requirements.txt), run these commands:

  ```
  pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  pip3 uninstall selenium
  pip3 install selenium==4.2.0
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method in the latest Selenium version. Try using driver.find_element.
EXAMPLE:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
time.sleep(5)

search_bar = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id-search-field")
search_bar.clear()
search_bar.send_keys("getting started with python")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.close()
```

NB: I have used Firefox instead of Chrome
(Upvote if this resolves your error)