# 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Whenever I run the code it brings up the Instagram page for about two seconds until it closes and then it gives me this error:

> 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

Whenever I run the code, it brings up the Instagram page for about two seconds until it closes and then it gives me this error:

> 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time, random

# Username and password of our instagram account
my_username = 'a'
my_password = 'm'

# Instagram username list for DM:
usernames = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3',]

# Messages:
messages = ['Hey! Please follow my page', 'Hey, how are you doing?', 'Hey']

# Delay time between messages in seconds:
between_messages = 2000

browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')

# Authorization:
def auth(username, password):
    try:
        browser.get('https://instagram.com')
        time.sleep(random.randrange(2, 4))

        input_username = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
        input_password = browser.find_element_by_name('username')

        input_username.send_keys(username)
        time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 2))
        input_password.send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 2))
        input_password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        browser.quit()

auth(my_username, my_password)
```

Comment: find_element_by_name has been deprecated instead use `browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')` and `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: The canonical question may be *[Selenium - Python - AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773206/selenium-python-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-el)*.

Answer (score 2):

`find_element_by_name`, and other methods starting with `find_element_by`, were deprecated in Selenium 4.0.0 with [this commit](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/8b2bab56187b026efa5b91dda1a3d4e06f36c451) and have been removed from Selenium as of version 4.3 with [this pull request](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/10712). The aforementioned PR has a comment saying how to update your code to use the `find_element()` method instead of `find_element_by_name`, `find_element_by_id`, etc.

Try changing your `find_element_by_name` calls to the below:

```
        input_username = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')
        input_password = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
```

Remember to add the following to your imports, or else the above two lines will not work:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: I understand that, I am a little new so I am sorry but I don't know exactly where to replace this stuff. If I could have a little more guidance that would be awesome, thanks for the help!

Comment: `input_username`, `input_password` should be replaced in `auth` function, and at the top  (or near the top) of your program, where the other imports are, add (without replacing) the `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` line.