# Selenium behave error>> AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'find_element'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, attributeerror, python-behave

I am unable to resolve this issue by following below answers

[Selenium - Python - AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773206/selenium-python-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-el)

I am using python behave with selenium webdriver in updated current version, feature file image attached & below is step file code.

[image]

```
import time
from behave import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


# access on described PDP
@given('I am on bundle item page named as Nestor Occasional Table Set')
def step_impl(context):
    context.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    context.driver.maximize_window()  # for maximise windows
    time.sleep(2)
    context.driver.get(
        "Project name removed myself")
    time.sleep(2)


@then('Verify the bundle Product sku')
def step_impl(context):
    prod_sku = context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-id' and @aria-label='ASL-T517-0-ROOM']")
    # print(prod_sku)
    displayed = prod_sku.is_displayed()
    print(displayed)
    time.sleep(5)
    # if displayed is True:
    #   print('product sku is visible on the screen because displayed value is', displayed)

    # else:
    #   print('product sku is not visible on the screen because displayed value is', displayed)
    # time.sleep(0.5)


@then('Verify the bundle Product price')
def step_impl(context):
    prod_price = context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='price-label' and @aria-label='Final Price']")
    # price_view = prod_price.is_displayed()
    # print(price_view)
    assert prod_price.text == "$540.00"
    time.sleep(0.5)


@when('I click on ADD TO CART button to add bundle product in to the cart')
def step_impl(context):
    context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button-basic theme-button btn-block']").click()
    time.sleep(7)


@then('Verify the added bundle Product in to the cart')
def step_imp(context):
    # added_product = context.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Bostwick Shoals Queen Panel Bed')
    added_product = context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='cart-prodname' and @class='pr-0']")
    prod_viewed = added_product.is_displayed()
    print(prod_viewed)
    time.sleep(1)


@then('Verify the added bundle Product price in to the cart')
def step_impl(context):
    # price = context.driver.find_element_by_link_text('$2699.00')
    # price = context.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='price-label' and @aria-label='Final Price']")
    price = context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='detail-type text-lg-right col-sm-4']")
    # price_view = prod_price.is_displayed()
    # print(price_view)
    assert price.text == "$540.00 Free Home Delivery*"
    assert price.text == "Free Home Delivery*"
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: @MarioMateaș I am getting error as mention in title , when i run code. I have attached feature file image and code steps file in code block area.

Comment: What is `context`? What line raises the error?