# Selenium -Attribute Error 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_class_name'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-3.9

I am trying to web scrape the site but I am constantly getting webdriver has no attribute find elements by  class name.

```
from selenium import WebDriver
url="https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Stationery-Shops/nct-10453443"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
data= driver.find_elements_by_class_name('resultbox_textbox')
print(data)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3244\3988657068.py in <module>
      3 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
      4 driver.get(url)
----> 5 data= driver.find_elements_by_class_name('resultbox_textbox')
      6 data

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_class_name'
'''
```

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72773269/7598774

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade the selenium version to make this syntax work (you're using the silenium version 3 syntax):

```
pip3 install 'selenium<4.0.0'
```

Or use the syntax of version 4:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
data = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'resultbox_textbox')
```

Comment: Thank you, It got resolved.