# How to log in to facebook using python?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium-webdriver, syntax-error, facebook-login

I want to log in to facebook but there is an error.
the code I am running:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys
import time

email = "your_email@example.com"
password = "your_password"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

email_field =
driver.find_element_by_id("email")
email_field.send_keys(email)

password_field =
driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
email_field.send_keys(password)

login_button =
driver.find_element_by_name("login")
login_button.click()

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

This error comes up when I use this code.. `File line 2 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

How can I fix this?

Comment: (1) Format the code properly. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: Hard to see from your bad formatting, but is there a newline after `keys`?

Comment: can you write me the code correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As clearly stated in the error, reason for above ERROR is, your `Keys` import syntax is incorrect.

It should be as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Having said that, you still have a few issues in your code:

- `email_field =`, `password_field =`, `login_button =`. You haven't assigned anything to these variables.
- `find_element_by_id` and `find_element_by_name` - Not sure what version of selenium you are using, but most likely you are using latest one and these methods are deprecated. So you may want to change the syntax as per latest version. Refer following answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73200177/7598774